# Why perfmon shows system process connects to several IP addresses?

Tags: windows

I have launched perfmon and it shows that system connects to multiple IP address like 69... and 74...

When I lookup these IP addresses no host seems to be known.

Is it normal ?

if yes why does it connect to these IP addresses ?

Update: Why would it send to google whereas I closed all apps including google chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the addresses using [WHOIS](http://www.whois.sc/).

I'm guessing at least the 74.* ones belong to Google.

Comment: Why would it send to google whereas I closed all apps including google chrome ?

Comment: I don't know. It could be Google Update Service. It could be *leftovers* of closed connections (are they 'established' or 'time-wait'?). It could be not Google at all -- only a *small part* of 74.* belongs to them.